# Appengine Django custom validations

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I write a custom django validation for Google AppEngine.

The case is I have a model which has a field whose value should be greater than an already existing value in the datastore for the same attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Django Forms?  You could do this with form validation.

Comment: yes I am using django forms... can you give an sample code to help me out...

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

You should run the code which checks the `form.is_valid()` and saving the entity in a transaction for consistency.  Look at the 'isolation and consistency' section here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html